# DNN 5.6 RadPanel side menu Issue

Tags: dotnetnuke, radpanelbar

I am working on DNN 5.6 website  where HTML pro module is being used which duplicates the sub menu (left) which is using the Telerik RadPanel control. It duplicates when the module is refreshed.
I tried using the Telerik RadMenu control but I want to display both Main menu pages and their Sub pages when menu page is selected on side menu.

Comment: You really should provide an actual question if you want assistance. At this point all you've done is make a statement.

Comment: My Question is how to avoid Duplication of sub menu left?